# How to use LDFLAGS in makefile

Tags: makefile, ldflags

I am new to Linux OS. I am trying to compile a `.c` file using a makefile. The math library has to be linked. My makefile looks like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -lm

all:client

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm *~ *.o client
```

When I run `make`, I get the following error:

```
"undefined reference to rint"
```

So it is not able to link the math library.

But when I compile explicitly using

```
gcc client.c -lm -o client
```

it successfully compiles.

So how should I change my makefile such that it works. I have already tried adding `LDFLAGS=-lm`. But I get the same error.

I should also add that when I run `make`, it expands to

```
gcc -Wall -lm client.c -o client
```

(notice that when I run `gcc` explicitly with `-lm` at the end, it works).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Your linker (ld) obviously doesn't like the order in which make arranges the GCC arguments so you'll have to change your Makefile a bit:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
LDFLAGS=-lm

.PHONY: all
all: client

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *~ *.o client

OBJECTS=client.o
client: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o client $(LDFLAGS)
```

In the line defining the *client* target change the order of `$(LDFLAGS)` as needed.

Comment: LDLIBS is for libraries, LDFLAGS should be used for flags/search paths (-L)

Comment: I also thought that -lm should be in LDFLAGS but as it turns out (see laindir's answer and https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html), it should be in LOADLIBES instead, and then everything works out of the box (ie without defining explicit rules)!

Comment: Where do you use source in your rules?  It's defined, but not used.  Having a hard time understanding this.

Comment: @MrPickles: You're right, `SOURCE` ist actually unused and can be removed.

Comment: @EmilVatai According to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-LDLIBS LOADLIBES is deprecated and LDLIBS should be used instead.

Comment: all should also be phony.

Comment: @falstaff Is LDLIBS standard make or is it a GNU extension (e.g. will this work under FreeBSD)?

Answer (score 63):

In more complicated build scenarios, it is common to break compilation into stages, with compilation and assembly happening first (output to object files), and linking object files into a final executable or library afterward--this prevents having to recompile all object files when their source files haven't changed. That's why including the linking flag `-lm` isn't working when you put it in `CFLAGS` (`CFLAGS` is used in the compilation stage).

The convention for libraries to be linked is to place them in either `LOADLIBES` or `LDLIBS` (GNU make includes both, but your mileage may vary):

```
LDLIBS=-lm
```

This should allow you to continue using the built-in rules rather than having to write your own linking rule. For other makes, there should be a flag to output built-in rules (for GNU make, this is `-p`). If your version of make does not have a built-in rule for linking (or if it does not have a placeholder for `-l` directives), you'll need to write your own:

```
client.o: client.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c -o $@ $<

client: client.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Comment: FWIW (just adding a usage scenario comment, to affirm what I see as the core of this answer), using `LDLIBS` instead of `LDFLAGS` is definitely a game-changer for the case of a simple foo.c -> foo via implicit rules type build (e.g. setting a target `default: foo`, with no other explicit settings, will successfully build foo from foo.c if any libraries needed are in `LDLIBS`, but it won't if they're in `LDFLAGS`.)

Answer (score 12):

The currently accepted answer is not correct according to the current (2022) `make` documentation here:

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

> `LDFLAGS:`
> Extra flags to give to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker, ‘ld’, such as -L. Libraries (-lfoo) should be added to the LDLIBS variable instead.
>
> `LDLIBS:`
> Library flags or names given to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker, ‘ld’. LOADLIBES is a deprecated (but still supported) alternative to LDLIBS. Non-library linker flags, such as -L, should go in the LDFLAGS variable.

Also the `LOADLIBES` mentioned in some responses above, has long been deprecated and should not be used anymore.

So, from the previous definitions, it seems the above example should be more properly written like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
LDLIBS=-lm
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/include

.PHONY: all
all: client

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *~ *.o client

OBJECTS=client.o
client: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)  -o client
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the order of the linking flags was not an issue in older versions of gcc. Eg `gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)` comes with Centos-6.7 happy with linker option before inputfile; but gcc with ubuntu 16.04 `gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) 5.3.1 20160413` does not allow.

Its not the gcc version alone, I has got something to with the distros