# problems with linking protobuf library

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am not familiar with makefile, here is my makefile

```
CC = gcc

TARGET = sample_client sample_server

CFLAGS += -g -I/usr/include
LDFLAGS += -g -lprotobuf-c -L/usr/lib

all:    $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):  lsp.o lspmessage.pb-c.o

%.o:    %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o 
    rm -f $(TARGET)
```

when I run make -f Make, I get these errors.

```
**@**:./$ make -f Makefile
gcc -g -I/usr/include  -g -lprotobuf-c -L/usr/lib  sample_client.c lsp.o lspmessage.pb-c.o   -o sample_client
lspmessage.pb-c.o: In function `lspmessage__get_packed_size':
./lspmessage.pb-c.c:19: undefined reference to `protobuf_c_message_get_packed_size'
lspmessage.pb-c.o: In function `lspmessage__pack':
./lspmessage.pb-c.c:26: undefined reference to `protobuf_c_message_pack'
lspmessage.pb-c.o: In function `lspmessage__pack_to_buffer':
./lspmessage.pb-c.c:33: undefined reference to `protobuf_c_message_pack_to_buffer'
lspmessage.pb-c.o: In function `lspmessage__unpack':
/home/**/Downloads/CSCE662/HW/skeleton-code/lspmessage.pb-c.c:41: undefined reference to `protobuf_c_message_unpack'
lspmessage.pb-c.o: In function `lspmessage__free_unpacked':
./lspmessage.pb-c.c:50: undefined reference to `protobuf_c_message_free_unpacked'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sample_client] Error 1
```

I do not know the reason. Thanks!

Comment: Oh god! I cannot believe it!! I was using `-lprotobuf` and omitting the `-c`! :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C linker works so that only libraries that come after a file are searched.

Try reordering the line like this:

`gcc -g -I/usr/include  -g  sample_client.c lsp.o lspmessage.pb-c.o   -o sample_client  -L/usr/lib -lprotobuf-c`

You can first run that from the command line to see if the problem is fixed. After that, to fix your Makefile, see this question [How to use LDFLAGS in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249610/how-to-use-ldflags-in-makefile).

Comment: Thank you! After I run this in command line, there is no errors related with undefined reference to `protobuf_c_message_get_packed_size'. So Makefile is not correct? How can I correct the Makefile?

Comment: after I run this command 
"gcc -g -I/usr/include -g sample_client.c lsp.o lspmessage.pb-c.o -o sample_client -L/usr/lib -lprotobuf-c", 
I wanna debug this program, 
 (gdb) sample_client,
 however I get this,
 (gdb) sample_client
Undefined command: "sample_client".  Try "help".

It seems it didn't generate the executable document.