# Undefined reference to log with make command

Tags: makefile

I need to just run the make command for makefile. But when I run this make command I get the error that
"undefined reference to `log'" because I know this fact that it doesn't include math Library and we have to include at runtime. I know that if I run this using  gcc comiler then i can write -lm at the end, it will include math library. My problem is I need to run it using make command that is- make lu.

In this if I write make lu -lm it is not linking math library. Please help

I have edited my make file

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
BENCHMARK=ep
BENCHMARKU=EP

include ../config/make.def

OBJS = ep.o ${COMMON}/c_print_results.o ${COMMON}/c_${RAND}.o \
       ${COMMON}/c_timers.o ${COMMON}/c_wtime.o

include ../sys/make.common
LDLIBS=-lm
LDFLAGS=-lm


${PROGRAM}: config ${OBJS}
    ${CLINK} ${CLINKFLAGS} -o ${PROGRAM} $(LDFLAGS) $(LOADLIBES) ${OBJS} ${C_LIB}


ep.o:       ep.c npbparams.h
    ${CCOMPILE} ep.c

clean:
    - rm -f *.o *~ 
    - rm -f npbparams.h core
```

Comment: Show us the command that works (without Make).

Comment: Command that works- gcc lu.c -lm. I have installed NAS parallel benchmarks and to run these benchmarks I have to run command- make lu –

Comment: i think this answers your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249610/how-to-use-ldflags-in-makefile Basically you need to use ldflags in makefile to link math lib at compile time

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
LDLIBS=-lm
```

in your Makefile.

Comment: I added the code given above but I'm still having same problem. Please Help.

SHELL=/bin/sh
BENCHMARK=ep
BENCHMARKU=EP

include ../config/make.def

OBJS = ep.o ${COMMON}/c_print_results.o ${COMMON}/c_${RAND}.o \
       ${COMMON}/c_timers.o ${COMMON}/c_wtime.o

include ../sys/make.common
LDLIBS=-lm
LDFLAGS=-lm


${PROGRAM}: config ${OBJS}
    ${CLINK} ${CLINKFLAGS} -o ${PROGRAM} $(LDFLAGS) $(LOADLIBES) ${OBJS} ${C_LIB}


ep.o:       ep.c npbparams.h
    ${CCOMPILE} ep.c

clean:
    - rm -f *.o *~ 
    - rm -f npbparams.h core