# Simple makefile for LibElemental

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, mpich

I would like to use [libElemental](http://libelemental.org/) as a library after installing it as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/elemental/Elemental
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../Elemental
make
make install
```

Install is successful & examples build. I have limited `makefile` experience, but would like to avoid using `cmake` so I can easily integrate elsewhere.

I have one file: `test.cpp`:

```
#include <El.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my unsuccessful `makefile` attempt:

```
CFLAGS = -O3 -std=gnu++11
LDFLAGS := -lEl
CC = mpicc.mpich2
CXX = mpicxx.mpich2

all: test
test: test.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) test.cpp -o test
```

Here is a snippet of the linker errors I receive:

`/tmp/ccgDsmEV.o: In function __static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/local/include/El/number_theory/lattice/LLL.hpp:316: undefined reference to El::Timer::Timer(std::string const&)'
:
:
/tmp/ccgDsmEV.o:/usr/local/include/El/number_theory/lattice/LLL.hpp:318: more undefined references to El::Timer::Timer(std::string const&)' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1`

Any help or pointers to help me resolve this is much appreciated!

Comment: Try `$(CXX) test.cpp $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o test`. No guarantees though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use LDFLAGS in makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249610/how-to-use-ldflags-in-makefile)

Comment: `would like to avoid using cmake so I can easily integrate elsewhere`

But that's what CMake is for.

Comment: Yes, but I have no control over what I'm integrating with currently and cannot use cmake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to commenters @andars and @Tsyvarev for pointing out that my error was the placement of `$(LDFlAGS)`. Other than this there just remains the matter of pointing to dynamic libraries installed by libElemental. Here is the final makefile:

```
CXX=mpicxx.mpich

LIB_PATHS:=-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/lib
CXXFLAGS:=-std=gnu++11 -O3
LDFLAGS:=-lEl

all: test
test: test.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIB_PATHS) test.cpp -o test $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f test
```

I could also skip adding `$(LIB_PATHS)` and just set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/lib`

**NOTE:** that since libElemental uses `mpich` instead of `openmpi` (as seen in the makefile), run executables with `mpirun.mpich` instead of just `mpirun` or you'll get undefined behavior.