# What is cflags's function?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

In this issue, CFLAGS set as path:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149359/what-is-the-correct-syntax-to-add-cflags-and-ldflags-to-configure

In this issue, CFLAGS set as compile option:

[How to use LDFLAGS in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249610/how-to-use-ldflags-in-makefile)

I am confused.

Comment: That first post is not "set as path". It's passing a compile option. The option is an include path.

Comment: any good link introduce these options?

Comment: GCC cflags https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=gcc+cflags → Option-Summary → https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CFLAGS stands for compiler flags. LDFLAGS is for linker flags.

CFLAGS is used to pass flags to tell the compiler information on how to build a file(s).

In your link it is used to pass the path of header file so that the compiler knows where to find them. This is done with the `-I` flag and is used like this: `-I<path>`. There are many flags you can pass to the compiler. Some common ones are:

- -c : compile only (don't link). This is used to compile a c/cpp file into an object (.o) file.
- -o : output name. This is used to specify the output name. E.g. `gcc -c fred.c -o fred.o` or `gcc fred.c -o fred`
- -I : this is used (as explained above) to add an include path: `-I.` includes the current directory. `-Ianother/sub/dir` includes ./another/sub/dir. Note there is no space after the -I.

Your best bet is to start with a really basic tutorial (don't worry it gets advance quite quickly):

Like [this](https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/gnumake.php) or [this](https://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/)